# The import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton cannot be resolved[Eclipse]

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

**The import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton cannot be resolved[Eclipse]**

Project Built target-**API 23**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

**Added jar lib folder** :

> android-support-v7-appcompat.jar
>
> appcompat-v7-23.1.1-sources.jar
>
> design-23.1.1-sources.jar

Comment: Which IDE you are using for development? Android Studio or Eclipse? bcz you tagged both

Comment: @OnkarNene, rejected your edit to answer below. Add your own answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **Android Studio** -

then try to add this in your `build.gradle`(app level)

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1' 
compile 'android-support-v7-appcompat:23.1.1'
```

as you are targeting to **API 23**

Comment: Can you provide the link to download jar only?

Comment: Ok, what about Eclipse Android?

Answer (score 3):

Cannot resolve class

```
android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
```

use this one

```
com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
```

Comment: I can preview it successfully in Android Studio.But when i am try to compile it,It will report an Error:
"Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton"
My `build.gradle`:
    'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    junit:junit:4.12
    'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'